# DateTime property causing new migration update even without any update on model in Entity Framework core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In entity framework, if I run the command "`add-migration <name>`" in package manager console, each and every time it creates migration with some update commands for the property datetime.

**Model:**

```
public class TestDetailBase
    {
        public string TestTitle { get; set; }
        public int TotalTimeinMinutes { get; set; }
        public double PassMarkPercent { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

**Migration Code:**

```
public partial class newMigration : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "TestDetails",
                keyColumn: "TestDetailId",
                keyValue: 1,
                columns: new[] { "CreatedDate", "UpdatedOn" },
                values: new object[] { new DateTime(2020, 3, 2, 8, 16, 33, 900, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(543), new DateTime(2020, 3, 2, 8, 16, 33, 900, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(543) });
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
                table: "TestDetails",
                keyColumn: "TestDetailId",
                keyValue: 1,
                columns: new[] { "CreatedDate", "UpdatedOn" },
                values: new object[] { new DateTime(2020, 3, 2, 8, 16, 19, 148, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(4304), new DateTime(2020, 3, 2, 8, 16, 19, 148, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(4304) });
        }
    }
```

I don't want to update the records which already inserted as seed data in previous migration. But If I create new migrations, the above additional migration code is automatically injecting to the migration.

Comment: Do you seed any values to this table?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are using DateTime.UtcNow as the default value for CreatedDate property. Please show us this code too

Comment: @SirRufo yea. Just found it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your are inserting your Seed's data, Don't use DateTime.Now for initial DateTime Properties.
probably in your EntityConfiguration file you are inserting this data with **HasData** method.

Comment: or set the `DateTime` property inside `HasData` like this: `Created = new DateTime(2022, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0) ` - in my case I had to set the time as well

Answer (score 0):

adding this to HasData is fetching the migration update each time:
new DateTime(2023, 4, 17, 9, 57, 33, 970, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddTicks(1250));

Comment: can anyone help to change this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).